# Button background color change not working

Tags: java, button, intellij-idea, colors

I have a problem with the background color of a button.

When clicked, it changes to a color that I didn't specify in my code. When I move my cursor away from the button (still holding the mouse button) it changes color to the one I defined in the code.

I am changing color with the following `ChangeListener` method:

```
btn1.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();

        if (model.isRollover()) {
            btn1.setBackground(new Color(166,166, 166));
        } else if (model.isPressed()) {
            btn1.setBackground(new Color(255, 64, 0));
        } else {
            btn1.setBackground(new Color(201, 201, 201));
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a screen shot of all situations:

1. Normal
2. Hover
3. Clicked **(bug)**
4. Clicked and moved cursor away from button

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the mouse on top of a button makes the model both armed and pressed. As long as the mouse remains down, the model remains pressed, even if the mouse moves outside the button. On the contrary, the model is only armed while the mouse remains pressed within the bounds of the button. [ButtonModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonModel.html)

Comment: Thank u for response. Ok I understand whats going on but i dont know how toapply that in to the code.
Sth like that isnt working
`else if (model.isArmed()) {
                    btn1.setBackground(new Color(255, 64, 0));
                } `